# How to avoid memory leaks with document.createElement?

Tags: javascript, dom, memory-leaks

Does the following code leak memory?

That is, if its output weren't being copied into the `console` here, could `fileUploadPrompt()` be run an unbounded number of times to retrieve an unbounded number of files without having to reload the page to free RAM?

Or do I need to be destroying the temporary variable `e` somehow? Should I put a single `<input>` element in a closure and re-use it for all calls to `fileUploadPrompt`?

```js
async function fileUploadPrompt(multiple = false) {
  const e = document.createElement('input');
  e.type = 'file';
  e.multiple = multiple;
  let cp = changePromise(e); // create before .click() to avoid race condition
  e.click();
  await cp;
  return multiple ? e.files : e.files[0];
}


/*  Helper method  */

function changePromise(target) {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    target.addEventListener('change', resolve, {once: true}));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fileUploadPrompt(true).then(files=>Array.from(files).forEach(file=>
console.log(({name: file.name, lastModified: file.lastModified, size: file.size, type: file.type}))))">
Get Some Files</button>
```

Comment: The element was never added to the DOM, so it should be garbage collected once it's no longer needed.

Comment: Nothing references the local temporary `e` object after the function has completed, so there is no reason to expect this to leak memory.